# My wife's FB page is hijacked (hacked). How to get it back?

Tags: facebook, hacked

My wife's FB page is hacked and hijacked. I can see the page on my friends list (her profile picture is gone) but all of her pics and threads are there.

But when she tried to log in, she got into a fake page, with someone else. She managed to remove that page. However, none of her credentials (emails / phone #) works to get the original page back?

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thank you,